# How to get data types of multiple columns?

Tags: sql

I have a column in a table that contains names of columns of another table.
I wish to automate the process of finding the data types corresponding to all the column names.

If it were 1 column, I would've used:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE     
     TABLE_NAME = 'table' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'column'
```

However there are muliple columns.
For instance,

```
Columns
---------
A
B
C    
D
```

Now how to automate this process of finding the data type corresponding to each column name?

Ps. The name of the table that possesses these columns is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caveat:** Case of the strings in the `WHERE` clause is important

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE     
     TABLE_NAME = 'table' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME IN ('a', 'b', 'c' ,'d');
```

example:

```
> select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where
         table_name='posts' and column_name in ('id', 'creationdate');
 column_name  |          data_type          
--------------+-----------------------------
 id           | integer
 creationdate | timestamp without time zone
(2 rows)
```